# Frequent 5 second freezes in CS:GO

Tags: technical-issues, counter-strike-global-offensive

When I just started to play CS:GO, I noticed that my game kept on freezing, having a black screen, and sometimes even crash all while having a sound loop. It used to last around 20 seconds, but after I lowered my graphics settings, it went down to 8.

Recently, after the new update, the game stopped having the black screen, but it still froze for about five seconds.  I have tried numerous ways to fix this.  A few are:

- Verifying game cache
- Preloading maps using `cl_forcepreload 1`
- Lowering graphics settings to the bare minimum.

Internet doesn't seem to be a problem, since I always have extraordinarly low ping, even when connecting with servers across the country. I've googled this problem a lot already, to no avail.

(FYI, I also have the alt-tab crash issue, but that doesn't bother me a lot.)

Answer (score 1):

There's a number of fixes listed in a megathread here:
http://steamcommunity.com/app/730/discussions/0/618458030659574249/

Try them out, make sure to read through them first though and see if the fix is related to the issue you're experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it's a hardware related issue. I had a gaming computer with a damaged motherboard that behaved in similar ways. It's either a hardware issue or software fix you could probably find on steam.